# Overlay effect works with mouse but not with keyboard

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem. I'm building portfolio page, and now I want to make it easy to navigate for people that can't use the mouse.

> What does the outline property do? It provides visual feedback for
>   links that have "focus" when navigating a web document using the TAB
>   key (or equivalent). This is especially useful for folks who can't use
>   a mouse or have a visual impairment. If you remove the outline you are
>   making your site inaccessible to these people.

I built it so you can navigate all the links on my page using `TAB` key and you can open that link using `ENTER` key.

But...

I have nice visual effect with overlay. You can see images of apps, and only when you hover the mouse above that picture you can see links.

So `TAB` is working and you can select a link using keyboard but you can't see active links, because that overlay effect works only with the mouse (while mouse is hovering above particular picture).

It is hard to explain by words, so I recorded a short video:
https://youtu.be/IQbXL7iyG6w?t=5

Any idea how to fix this? Overlay effect should be tiggered by TAB navigation as well.

GitHub code:
https://github.com/elminsterrr/portfolio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple jquery code. First change your css

## CSS

change this:

```
#portfolio .inner-content:hover .overlay-content {
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

with:

```
#portfolio .inner-content:hover .overlay-content {
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
#portfolio .inner-content .overlay-content.focus_test{
    top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

## jQuery:

```
 $('.overlay-content p a').focus(function(){
    $(this).parents('.overlay-content').addClass('focus_test');
  });
  $('.overlay-content p a').blur(function(){
      $(this).parents('.overlay-content').removeClass('focus_test');
  });
```

Comment: Great answer! It works like a charm! You made my day! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're showing your overlay on `:hover` when using `TAB` the elements get focused, so you have to add the `:focus` selector to your css for your overlay to show.

`.my-class:hover .my-overlay { ... }` => `.my-class:focus .my-overlay, .my-class:hover .my-overlay { ... }`

Comment: That didn't work :( It worked for buttons in the navbar, but not for portfolio section... I added :focus to all my elements that had :hover.